# creating single media stream from multiple <audio> elements?

Tags: javascript, audio, mediarecorder, mediastream

I have an SVG that produces audio based on keypresses, and I want to record the audio coming from it in my react app.

In the svg I have a group of audio elements like this:

```
<svg id="keyboard_svg">

*other svg stuff*

   <g id="keyboard">
     <audio src="https://arweave.net/<hash>/fileName1.flac"></audio
     <audio src="https://arweave.net/<hash>/fileName2.flac"></audio>
     <audio src="https://arweave.net/<hash>/fileName3.flac"></audio>
     <audio src="https://arweave.net/<hash>/fileName4.flac"></audio>
   </g>
</svg>
```

in my react app I get access to the audio elements like this:

```
const svg = document.getElementById("keyboard_svg")
const sound = svg.getElementById("Electric Piano")
```

so `sound` is the group of audio elements. I can iterate through them like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<sound.children.length; i++) {
   //do something with sound.children[i]
}
```

the SVG is of a keyboard that users can use their keyboard to play.
my goal is to record the audio from these elements in javascript.
My understanding is that I can create a MediaStream object, add MediaStreamTracks to it, and then pass the MediaStream in the MediaRecorder constructor. But maybe Im misunderstanding how it works.

What I've tried:

```
let stream = new MediaStream()
for(let i=0; i<sound.children.length; i++) {
    stream.addTrack(sound.children[i])
}
```

this doesnt work because audio elements are not of type MediaStreamTrack.

let audio = new Audio()

```
for(let i=0; i<sound.children.length; i++) {
        let source = document.createElement("source")
        source.src = sound.children[i].src
        audio.appendChild(source)
    }
```

so `audio` is gives me this:

```
<audio>
   <source src="https://arweave.net/<hash>/fileName1.flac">
   <source src="https://arweave.net/<hash>/fileName2.flac">
   <source src="https://arweave.net/<hash>/fileName3.flac">
   <source src="https://arweave.net/<hash>/fileName4.flac">
</audio>
```

then I tried:

```
let stream = audio.captureStream()
```

but if I pass that into a MediaRecorder, i get:

```
Failed to construct 'MediaRecorder': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'
```

So thats where im stuck at basically. Im aware of these other functions

```
AudioContext.createMediaElementSource()
AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource()
AudioContext.createMediaStreamTrackSource()
MediaStreamTrackGenerator()
```

it sounds like theyre what I need but I cant figure out how to use them. Ive tried a bunch of other things but what I listed above is what I think makes most sense, but still doesnt work.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you're going to need the Web Audio API, including some of the functions that you mentioned in your question.

Start of by creating a new `AudioContext` and select your `<audio>` elements. Loop over each `<audio>` element and use [`AudioContext.createMediaElementSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource#example) to create a playable source from the elements.

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const audioElements = document.querySelectorAll('#keyboard audio');
const sources = Array.from(audioElements).map(
  audioElement => audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement)
);
```

From here you need to connect all the sources into the `MediaRecorder`. You can't do that directly, because the `MediaRecorder` only accepts a [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) instance as argument.

To connect the two, use a [`MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode). This node is able to both receive the inputs from the created sources and create an output in the form of a `MediaStream`.

Loop over the sources and connect them with the `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`. Then pass the `stream` property of `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` into the `MediaRecorder` constructor.

---

**Edit**:
I've included the usage of a [`GainNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode), which basically is a volume control, but can also be used to collect multiple inputs into a single `AudioNode`.

In this case we connect all the `sources` to the `GainNode` en than connect the `GainNode` to the speakers **and** the `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`. This way we can both monitor and stream our audio while both are coming from the same source.

This is an "easier" alternative over creating an `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` and reading the stream from the `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`.

---

```
const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
const mediaStreamDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

sources.forEach(source => {
  source.connect(gainNode);
});

gainNode.connect(mediaStreamDestination);
gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamDestination.stream);
```

From here, all you have to do is hit record and play your notes.

```
let recordingData = [];

mediaRecorder.addEventListener('start', () => {
  recordingData.length = 0;
});

mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
  recordingData.push(event.data);
});

mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
  const blob = new Blob(recordingData, { 
    'type': 'audio/mp3' 
  });
  
  // The blob is the result of the recording.
  // Handle the blob from here.
});

mediaRecorder.start();
```

**Note 1**: This solution is not written in React and should be modified to work with it. For example: `document.querySelectorAll` should never be used in a React app. Instead use the `useRef` hook to create a reference to the `<audio>` elements.

**Note 2**: The `<audio>` element is not a part of an SVG. You don't have to place the elements inside the SVG for them to work. Instead visually hide the `<audio>` elements and trigger them with, for example, an `onClick` prop.

Comment: sick! im working on this now. for me, I think the audio needs to be inside the svg, because (pls dont judge me lol) im storing it on the ethereum blockchain. so the svg is returned as a base64 encoded string that you can put into a web browser and play. So im building a frontend to allow recording. will it still work that way? also, is it alright use getElementById in react? thanks!!

Comment: UPDATE: IT WORKS!!!
I added a few things:
first I had to set the cross origin for each audio element like this: 
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

to hear the recording I did this:

let audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let recordedAudio = new Audio(audioUrl);
recordedAudio.play();

this plays it immediatly after recording, which ill change but I did this just to test. 

one thing is, when I call  createMediaElementSource(audio) it stops live playback, meaning you cant hear the keyboard while youre playing it, but it still records and plays back

Comment: does createMediaElementSource change the output of the sound? 
thanks again for your help!

Comment: 1. no idea if it would still work. You're talking about a React app in Base64. I have no experience there. No, `getElementById` should also be avoided unless absolutely necessary (it is not the *React way*). 2. Great to hear to figured out the playback. 3. I'm guessing it shouldn't. In what way does the output *change*? And you're welcome.

Comment: maybe I'm bad at articulating, the output changes meaning the audio doesnt come out of the speakers as i play the notes, it is recorded and plays back when i stop recording, but as I press the keys theres no audio. something to do with `audioContext.createMediaElementSource()` i _think_.  I wonder if I need to create a new audio element as the _output_ and set the `src` or `srcObject` to the media stream?

Comment: came up a solution! after I iterate through the audio elements i do this:
`let streamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamDestination.stream)`

`streamSource.connect(audioContext.destination)`

mostly through trial and error, lol. not 100% sure if this is the best way, but I think it makes sense and it in fact works!

Comment: Yes, connecting `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` to the `audioContext.destination` node is the correct way to do it. It's a virtual version of connecting a guitar to an amp with a cable, that's how I always try to visualize this API anyway :). I'll add it to the answer in case somebody else is wondering the same thing.

Comment: awesome, good analogy! last question, is `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode ` different from `createMediaStreamSource` ? i used `createMediaStreamSource` which creates a new `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode`, then connected that to the `audioContext.destination`

Comment: Ah, I see that I overlooked the usage of `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` in your previous comment. (They look so similar :).) Will correct in the answer. The `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` creates a stream which you can pass into, for example, a `MediaRecorder` instance. `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` is used to capture a stream which you then can pass through to other `AudioNode` instances.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article:
https://mitya.uk/articles/concatenating-audio-pure-javascript

```
var uris = [];
for(let i=0; i<sound.children.length; i++) {
    uris.push(sound.children[i].src);
}
let proms = uris.map(uri => fetch(uri).then(r => r.blob()));
Promise.all(proms).then(blobs => {
    let blob = new Blob([blobs[0], blobs[1]]),
        blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
        audio = new Audio(blobUrl);
    audio.play();
});
```